# Filtering lines based on common matching pattern (Unknown to User)

Tags: awk, sed, grep

My objective is to find the rule number that matches a source-ip and destination-ip

Example:

```
Source.IP -- 10.44.68.252
Destination -- 10.112.140.155
```

Filtering the configuration file with `grep "10.44.68.252\|10.112.140.155"` gives me the below list of commands.

I am manually need to look and find the rule number where the source and destination matches. In the below output rule 1515 matches is what I am looking for.

Is there any way to find it in same command?

```
cat test.txt | grep "10.44.68.252\|10.112.140.155"   
set nat source rule 39 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1008 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1010 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1036 destination address '10.44.68.252/32'  
set nat source rule 1037 destination address '10.44.68.252/32'  
set nat source rule 1099 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1104 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1515 destination address '10.44.68.252/32'  
set nat source rule 1515 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1516 destination address '10.44.68.252/32'  
set nat source rule 1517 source address '10.112.140.155/32'  
set nat source rule 1520 source address '10.112.140.155/32'
```

Tried multiple options in grep. None helped. sed may help. But I don't know sed.

Comment: Can you post some raw, unfiltered (with `grep`) data from the `test.txt` )including the desired part, of course).

Comment: @JamesBrown Presumably, these are `iptables` rules which doesn't give the op a luxury of fixed column data.

Comment: sed is for doing `s/old/new/`, that is all. That's not what you're trying to do so you shouldnt be considering using sed.

Comment: Can the same `rule` value show up multiple times indicated as a source or destination? e.g. could you have `1515` listed twice as a source for the same IP address?

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution :

```
awk -v sq="'" -v dest=10.44.68.252 -v src=10.112.140.155 '
(index($NF,sq dest "/") && $6 == "destination") ||
(index($NF,sq src "/") && $6 == "source"){found[$5]++}
END{
for(key in found)
 if(found[key]>1)
   print key;
}
' filename
```

**Output**

```
1515
```

<sub>**Note:** I would rather post this as a comment except for its length. Also  see the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55673319/revisions) suggested by @ed-morton which I implemented</sub>

Comment: @EdMorton Great ! Implemened ! Thank You :-)

Comment: Hmm, won't that report the rule as matching even if it's never recorded as a destination but it shows up twice as a source? I think you need more than just the `found[]` array to track both src and dest separately for a given rule. I suppose the rule **may** be unique for every src/dest though, idk. You're definitely on the right track for how to do this robustly, efficiently, and portably.

Comment: @EdMorton It does and for the same reason. I wanted to put this answer as a comment. But seeing the `grep` output it seemed that no two records can have the same rule number except when it has different types of addresses(source/destination). This is one assumption I made. In any case, knowing the rule number where a duplicate exists is definitely useful here as the op can modify those at its whim. Let better sense prevail :-)

Comment: I've asked the OP in a comment, we'll see what she says. This is definitely by far the best answer given what we know so far.

Answer (score 0):

Some bashisms, but this should do it:

```
sort -uk5 data.txt>&dat && join -j5 <(fgrep e\ ad<dat) <(fgrep n\ ad<dat) | awk '{gsub(/'"'"'/,"");print$1,$8,$NF}' | column -tR1,2,3 -N rule,src,dest
```

---

```
rule                src             dest
1515  10.112.140.155/32  10.44.68.252/32
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cat test.txt | grep "10.44.68.252\|10.112.140.155" | awk '{ print $5 }' | uniq -d
```

output

```
1515
```

Comment: You can do with awk, what ever you could do with `cat-grep-awk` combination.

Comment: That will fail with false matches due to the lack of anchors and the `.`s meaning "any char" and it'd produce the same (but wrong) output if the IP addresses were flipped in context in the input (i.e. the source one only appeared as a dest and vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWK solution:

```bash
awk -v sq="'" -v src=10.112.140.155 -v dst=10.44.68.252 '
  BEGIN {
    s_regex = sq src "/"; d_regex = sq dst "/"
  }
  /source address/   &&    $8 ~ s_regex {s[si] = $5; si++}
  /destination address/ && $8 ~ d_regex {d[di] = $5; di++}
  END {
    for (i in s) for (j in d) if (s[i] == d[j]) {print s[i]}
  }
  ' FILENAME
```

Explanation:

- For lines matching source or destination address and the 8th field matching the IP, add the rule in the 5th field to an array s or d respectively. These arrays track the rule numbers matching the source or destination respectively.
- In the END block, loop through both arrays to find the first occurrence where that rule was seen in both arrays.
- Acknowledgements to @sjsam for the idea of using the AWK variables.